Limit of Eigenvalues of Matrix Expression
I would like to study the limit
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \lambda_{\min}  [x(I_n + xA)^{-1}] , $$
where $x \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ is a scalar, $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $A \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is a positive semidefinite matrix. The minimum eigenvalue of a matrix is denoted by $\lambda_{\min}[\cdot]$. I would like to compute the limit for a unknown matrix $A$ as a function of its maximum or minimum eigenvalues.
My thoughts are: since the term inside the brackets is positive definite for any $x \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$, the inverse in the limit always exists. For $x>0$, we can rewrite the limit as
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \lambda_{\min}  [(\frac{1}{x}I_n + A)^{-1}]  = \lambda_{\min}[A^{-1}] .$$
The problem here is that the inverse of $A$ is not defined if $A$ has not full rank, which may be the case. With small examples I programmed in Matlab I saw that the limit converges to $\frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}[A]}$, but I don't see how to explain that.
Can someone give some hints? Thanks in advance!

I suggest you look at the following: Since $A$ is symmetric it is diagonalizable. Say $A=S\cdot D\cdot S^{-1}$. Now $(I_n+xA)^{-1}$ is the same as $S(I_n+xD)^{-1}S^{-1}$. But $(I_n+xD)^{-1}$ just looks like:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{1+x\cdot\lambda_1} & \ldots & 0\\
 0 &\ddots & 0 \\
0 & \ldots & \dfrac{1}{1+x\cdot \lambda_n}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where the $\lambda_i$ are the diagonal entries of $D$ (respectively the eigenvalues of $A$). Can you take it from here? Let me know if you need further hints.

Thanks, got it from here!
